# Error while processing request (Azure)

Tags: android, azure, insert

I recently moved from one Azure account to another (long story). I've recreated all my Databases and I'm remade a mobile service for the application I'm working on in *java* for *android*. I'm trying to insert into my one table but receive the message, ***Error while processing request***. I've double checked my table names and they all match - as well as my connection strings. The odd thing is one my tables does insert but the other 2 give me that message when I try to? Any suggestions? I have checked all my connections string repeatedly, and as my Tables are dynamic, I don't have to set the columns, etc.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved my problem:

Instead of using exception.message() in my catch, I used exception.getCause() and realised I had (at some point some how) left one of my attributes/properties in my constructor blank. All fixed now.